# MVC Unobtrusive Validation Incorrectly Firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

We use data annotations in combination with the jQuery.validate.unobtrusive plugin for one of our applications and came across a unique, what appears to be a bug, today.

View Model Property

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must specifiy a point value for the contest entry")]
[Min(5, ErrorMessage = "The point value must be at least 5 points for this contest")]
[DisplayName("Points required for entry:")]
public int RequiredPoints { get; set; }
```

View

```
<li class="reqpoints">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.RequiredPoints) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RequiredPoints)</li>
```

Resulting HTML

```
<li class="reqpoints">

    <label for="RequiredPoints"></label>
    <input id="RequiredPoints" class="input-validation-error" type="text" value="10" name="RequiredPoints" data-val-required="You must specifiy a point value for the contest entry" data-val-range-min="5" data-val-range="The point value must be at least 5 points for this contest" data-val-number="The field Points required for entry: must be a number." data-val="true"></input>

</li>
```

This works great if the number entered into the textbox is 5-9 or if the first digit is 5 or greater.  Any number from 10 through 49, 100-499, 1000-4999, etc gets rejected with the error message that it must be at least 5 points, almost as if it is truncating the last digits.  This is not going to the server and coming back, it is the jQuery validation portion that is firing off.  Has anyone seen an issue using `Min()` with a single integer value like this?

I should note we use this somewhere else where the minimum value is 100 and have no issues (that I am aware of) of any number greater than 100 being rejected.

Relevant versions:

- jQuery - 1.8.4
- jQuery.Validation - 1.12.0
- jQuery.validation.unobtrusive - 3.1.2

**Update**

If I change the `Min` attribute to have a minimum of 10, everything works as expected.  Additionally, if I use the `Range(5,99999)` data attribute, then all values seem to work as expected as well.  It appears that the combination of jQuery 1.8.4 and the latest versions of the validation plugins might have an issue with single digit minimum validation.

Comment: *At the end did you mean any number less than 100 is being rejected?* bad at reading sorry

Comment: @AdmiralAdama - No, meaning it works as it should/expected.  If a user inputs 99, rejected.  If they input 101, it works fine for that particular field in another view model (unrelated to this one).  In the instance I am having issues with, it rejects anything that doesn't start with a 5 or greater.  I mention the last example just to show it does work in other places in our application, just not this one instance?

Comment: Sorry I misread the last example.

Have you tried changing the number? Sounds like jquery isn't converting properly to integers. [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341564/jquery-validation-does-not-validate-numbers-properly)

Comment: @AdmiralAdama - no sweat!  While this question is up on SO, I am going to create a new project with the same file versions to see if I can replicate of if some other package is causing a problem.

Comment: Thanks. It seems really weird but this could be a bug in your versions of unobtrusive validation.

Comment: Hi.. Just curious to know what is the output if you enter, let say, 4 (something below 5)

Comment: @Ashish - rejects as expected

Comment: An alternative might be to use the Range Validator `[Range(5, 100)]`  - although its good to know why the min does not behave as expected

Comment: @Ashish - great minds think alike! that's what I did for now as a test case and it passed.  I am going to fire up a new project with minimal packages to see if I can confirm the behavior with the versions of jQuery I listed above.  I will update if I can replicate / report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a project we have been supporting for a few years now and I had to refresh some knowledge on the project.

The `Min()` attribute is actually part of the [DataAnnotationExtensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) package that adds some additional data annotations and plugs in with the jQuery validation framework.  Installing this package along with jQuery validation framework (all up to date) I can replicate this issue on a fresh, brand new project.

I will report this issue to the package authors but will leave this here in case anyone else using this package runs across this issue.  The work around is to use the `Range()` data annotation.

**Update**

[Issue reported here](https://github.com/srkirkland/DataAnnotationsExtensions/issues/60) - however, it does not appear this project has been officially updated in some time.  I may examine how we use this project and replace its components with official .NET bits.