# Regular expression data validation attribute does not return error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, model-validation

I have my model:

```
[RegularExpression("[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "GroupId must be a number")]
public int? GroupId { get; set; }
```

And WebApi application. I expect controller to return error message like this:

```
{
   "$id": "1",
   "Message": "GroupId must be a number"
}
```

For example, when I have `Required` attribute, it works just fine:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(64, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Name must be between 1 and 64 characters long.")]
public string Name { get; set; }

{
   "$id": "1",
   "Message": "The Name field is required."
}
```

And `ReqularExpression` just does not work.

I have also tried:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "GroupId must be a number")]
[RegularExpression("[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "GroupId must be a number")]
[RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]+)$", ErrorMessage = "GroupId must be a number")]
```

I have custom `ActionFilterAttribute` on my WebApi controller. 
And it creates response using `HttpActionContext actionContext.modelState`.

modelState.Values[0].Errors[0].Exeption value is `null` for `Regex Attribute`, and the `Exeption` text is `"Could not convert string to integer:  Path 'GroupId '.`

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this?

PS

I create custom validation attribute:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                int parseResult;

                if (!int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out parseResult))
                    return new ValidationResult("Value must be a number");
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
```

Now `object value` comes `null` if non-numeric value was specified.

Also I tried DataAnnotationsExtensions package, it did not help.

P.S.S.

Apparently, it because `model binding` takes place before `validation`.
You can find more information here [Server side validation of int datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921067/server-side-validation-of-int-datatype)